# Session table to a database?

Tags: php, database

How can I send `session[table]` to database in PHP?

Like that:

```
session_start();
session_register('table');
$qty=$_POST[txtQty];
$pid=$_REQUEST[pid];
$data=@mysql_query("SELECT * from products where productid=".$pid,$con) or die(mysql_error());
$table=$_SESSION[table];
while($row=@mysql_fetch_array($data))
{   
    $table.='<tr><td>'.$row[name].'></td>
<td>'.$row[price].'</td><td>'.$qty.'</td><td>'.$row[price]*$qty.'</td>
<td>Delete</td></tr>';
    $_SESSION[table]=$table; 
}
```

I want to send  `$_SESSION[table]=$table;` to database.

Comment: first using `$_SESSION[table]` would produce some warning and it's kind of bad.

Answer (score 1):

you seems to use the `$_SESSION` has a cache, the `$_SESSION` variable is not intended to do that. It is for stocking user related variables and it should/could of kilobytes worth (even less).

If you are looking for some cache mechanism there [memcached](http://memcached.org/), [APC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php), and many others.

also to be noted in my comment `$_SESSION[table]` will generate warning, you should add the quotes like `$_SESSION['table']`.

Also it's a good practice to develop with the maximum level of warning (i.e. `error_reporting(E_ALL);`), it would help you to find possible bugs/issues more easily.

To put back the `$_SESSION['table']` in database your would have to somehow store it as an array and then loop thought that array and do subsequent `INSERT` queries.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what the intentions are, but if you want to modify the way sessions work you'll need to define your own session functions and set them with [`session_set_save_handler()`](http://us.php.net/session_set_save_handler).

Answer (score 1):

You can modify and use this class, it keeps session in DB

```
class MySQLSession
{
  protected $resource = null;
  protected $db = 'base';
  protected $table = 'session';
  protected $id_col = 'sess_id';
  protected $data_col = 'sess_data';
  protected $time_col = 'sess_time';

  public function __construct($context, $parameters = null){
    session_set_save_handler(array($this, 'sessionOpen'),
                             array($this, 'sessionClose'),
                             array($this, 'sessionRead'),
                             array($this, 'sessionWrite'),
                             array($this, 'sessionDestroy'),
                             array($this, 'sessionGC'));

    session_start();
  }

  public function sessionClose(){
    return true;
  }

  public function sessionDestroy($id){
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id, $this->resource);
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM '.$this->table.' WHERE '.$this->id_col.' = \''.$id.'\'';
    if (@mysql_query($sql, $this->resource)){
      return true;
    }
    $error = 'MySQLSessionStorage cannot destroy session id "%s"';
    $error = sprintf($error, $id);
    throw new Exception($error);
  }

  public function sessionGC($lifetime){
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM '.$this->table.' '.
           'WHERE '.$this->time_col.' + INTERVAL '.$lifetime.' SECOND < NOW()';
    if (@mysql_query($sql, $this->resource)){
      return true;
    }
    $error = 'MySQLSessionStorage cannot delete old sessions';
    throw new Exception($error);
  }

  public function sessionOpen($path, $name){
    $this->resource = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'pass', true);
    mysql_select_db($this->db, $this->resource);
    return true;
  }

  public function sessionRead($id){
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id, $this->resource);

    $sql = 'SELECT '.$this->data_col.' ' .
           'FROM '.$this->table.' ' .
           'WHERE '.$this->id_col.' = \''.$id.'\'';
    $result = @mysql_query($sql, $this->resource);
    if ($result != false && @mysql_num_rows($result) == 1){
      $data = mysql_fetch_row($result);
      return $data[0];
    }else{
      $sql = 'INSERT INTO '.$this->table.' ('.$this->id_col.', ' .
             $this->data_col.', '.$this->time_col.') VALUES (' .
             '\''.$id.'\', \'\', NOW())';

      if (@mysql_query($sql, $this->resource)){
        return '';
      }
      $error = 'MySQLSessionStorage cannot create new record for id "%s"';
      $error = sprintf($error, $id);
      throw new Exception($error);
    }
  }

  public function sessionWrite($id, &$data){
    $id   = mysql_real_escape_string($id, $this->resource);
    $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data, $this->resource);
    $sql = 'UPDATE '.$this->table.' ' .
           'SET '.$this->data_col.' = \''.$data.'\', ' .
           $this->time_col.' = NOW() ' .
           'WHERE '.$this->id_col.' = \''.$id.'\'';

    if (@mysql_query($sql, $this->resource)){
      return true;
    }
    $error = 'MySQLSessionStorage cannot write session data for id "%s"';
    $error = sprintf($error, $id);
    throw new Exception($error);
  }

  public function shutdown(){
  }
}
```